# Rounding error in Ruby Time

Tags: ruby, time, rounding-error

EDIT: it appears in timev.h that sub seconds are represented as integers instead of floats?

Even if I know the rounding errors related to the implementation of IEEE 754 floating values, I'm very surprised of this one:

```
Time.utc(1970,1,1,0,0,12.860).strftime("%H:%M:%S,%L") # => "00:00:12,859"
```

Usually, precision errors are reported for the 8th or 10th digit after the comma, and I well understand why. But in this case, the last significant digit of my value is impacted, and it appears to be a more serious error than in other well-known precision cases. Moreover, this is a part of the Time class and I don't know any way to fix it in a program. Other reported rounding float errors may sometimes be fixed with a use of different classes, but in this case I don't see any interesting class to use.

My environment:

```
phil@eldiablo ~ % uname -a                                                                11-02-2013 09:38:49 
Linux eldiablo.loria.fr 3.5.0-23-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 13:05:29 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
/home/phil
phil@eldiablo ~ % ruby -v                                                                 11-02-2013 09:38:51 
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
```

EDIT: So, two questions about this: Is it or not a bug? And how to handle this side-effect if I need such a precision with the Time class? Any idea or workaround?

Comment: As I don't know the internal implementation of Time class, I would like to be sure it's not a bug, what can be considered as my first question. Second question is how to handle this side-effect if I need such a precision with the Time class?

Comment: More suprising: If I well understand the source code, sub seconds in Time class are defined as VALUE, i.e. as an unsigned integer, i.e. not as a float. In this case, how this kind of error could happen?

Answer (score 0):

The seeming seeriousness of this error derives from the fact, that the float string is trimmed without the float being rounded. When you look at

```
Time.utc( 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 12.860 ).subsec
#=> ( 60517119992791 / 70368744177664 )
```

While converting it to float gives

```
Time.utc( 1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 12.860 ).subsec.to_f
#=> 0.8599999999999994
```

The behavior you are seeing might be understood as bug as well as a feature. In my opinion, this would deserve to be corrected to a more intuitive outcome. In my opinion, you should go to http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/ and report surprise there.

Comment: That's what SO is for :-) When you stay here longer, you will learn all about the manners, as well as about SO content nazis :-)